# angularjs how can i bind textbox values on button click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Please help me how can I bind these ng-model(a,b) values during button click event

```
    <input type="text"  ng-model="a"/><b>Enter A Value</b>
    <input type="text" ng-model="b" /><b>Enter b Value</b>
    <button ng-click="Addition()">add</button>
```

**Angular.js**

```
$scope.Addition = function () {
        $scope.a = 10;
        $scope.b = 20;

        $state.go('Add', {
            a: $scope.a,
            b: $scope.b
        }
}
```

Here when i click on button a=10 b=20 values moves but not what I entered

Comment: don't define in the addition function

Comment: ok i change it as DoAdd()

Comment: this much code is enough ,
 
   `$scope.Addition = function () {
            $state.go('Add', {
                a: $scope.a,
                b: $scope.b
            }
    }`

Comment: then why im not able to chk my values in console or in result

Comment: do u have any urls

Comment: what output you are expecting ?

Comment: when i enter a=2 b=3 these values i need not 10,20value these(10,20) i hot coded but i need 2,3 values which i enter from the i/p

Comment: I think you want to do addition when you click the button click based on your entered inputs right

Comment: `$scope.Addition = function () { console.log('a value'+$scope.a);  console.log('b vlaue'+$scope.b); console.log('addition'+($scope.a+$scope.b)) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its working fine i don't see any problem

```js
var app= angular.module("myApp",[])

app.controller("myController",function($scope){
$scope.Addition= function(){
console.log("Value of a is "+$scope.a);
console.log("Value of b is "+$scope.b);

}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
 <input type="text"  ng-model="a"/><b>Enter A Value</b>
    <input type="text" ng-model="b" /><b>Enter b Value</b>
    <button ng-click="Addition()">add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: i only removed `$scope.a = 10;   $scope.b = 20;`

Answer (score 0):

try this
on html

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="a"/><b>Enter A Value</b>
<input type="text" ng-model="b" /><b>Enter b Value</b>
<button ng-click="Addition(a,b)">add</button>
```

on js

```
$scope.Addition(a,b){
    console.log(a + " " + b)
}
```